# Reasoning about subgroups $H \le PSL(2,q)$ based on knowledge about subgroups of normalizers in it

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, sylow-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite permutation group acting transitively and non-regularly on $\Omega$. Also suppose that each non-trivial element has at most two fixed points and $|\Omega| \ge 4$.

Let me note that for a group acting that way, if $1 \ne X \le G_{\alpha}$, then as $N_G(X)$ acts on the set of fixed points of $X$, because if $X^g = X$ then $X\le G_{\alpha^g}$, and as $X$ has at most two fixed point we have that $|N_G(X) \cap G_{\alpha} : N_G(X)| \le 2$ by the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Also if $p \in \pi(G_{\alpha})$ and $p$ is odd, then $G_{\alpha}$ contains a full Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, for if $P$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G_{\alpha}$, then $$|G:G_{\alpha}| \equiv \mbox{number of fixed points on }\alpha^G \pmod{p}$$
and hence is not divisible by $p$.

These facts are used in the following arguments, for which I ask this question:

> Let $G \cong PSL(2, q)$ with $q = r^m \ge 13$. Suppose $q \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Let $\alpha \in \Omega$ and set $H := G_{\alpha} \ne 1$. Suppose $r$ divides $|H|$. Then $H$ contains a Sylow $r$-subgroup of $G$ and hence a subgroup of index at most two of its normalizer. This means that $H$ contains a subgroup of order $\frac{q-1}{4}$. As $q \ge 7$ and as $q-1$ is divisible by $4$, we know that $q-1 \ge 8$. Hence $H$ contains a subgroup of order $(q-1)/2$ of $G$. Now by looking at the subgroup structure of $G$ we find that $H$ is the normalizer of a Sylow $r$-subgroup of $G$ whence $|\Omega| = q + 1$. Also if we let $\Omega$ denote the set of cosets of the normalizer of a Sylow $r$-subgroup in $G$, then $\Omega$ has $q+1$ elements and acts in the way described above.

How does the fact that $H$ contains a subgroup of index at most two of a  normalizer of a Sylow $r$-subgroup implies that $H$ contains a subgroup order $(q-1)/4$? And further why does the fact that $H$ contains a subgroup of order $(q-1)/2$ implies it must be the normalizer of a Sylow $r$-subgroup, and why does this implies that $|\Omega| = q + 1$?

The subgroup structure of $PSL(2,q)$ I have posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490555/properties-of-point-stabilizers-of-psl2-q), but it could also be seen in [this paper](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/o.h.king/KingBCC05.pdf).

Comment: As it says, all of these things follow from the subgroup structure of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$. Oddly enough, you haven't asked about the part that I do not find clear, which is the claim that $H$ contains a  subgroup of order $(q-1)/2$.

Comment: I do not see the connection. Can you say what subgroups are exactly involved? For the point you mentioned, here the fact that the normalizers of subgroups have at most index $2$ is involved, so it has something to to with that, but I am not 100% sure about that either, hoping it becomes clearer as my other questions get answered...

Comment: The normalizer of a Sylow $r$-subgroup of $G$ has order $q(q-1)/2$, hence the fact that $H$ has a subgroup of order at least $q(q-1)/4$. There are now only two possibilities for $H$, $H$ is the full Sylow normalizer of order $q(q-1)/2$ or the unique subgroup of index 2, which has order $q(q-1)/4$. I think in the second case there would elements fixing more than two points, but I am surpised that no details are given in the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There is not much more said in the original source, if you want you can take a look there, its Lemma 3.11 http://conway1.mathematik.uni-halle.de/~waldecker/MagaardWaldecker2fp.pdf

Comment: I see! They are applying Lemma 2.8 to the subgroup of $G_\alpha$ of order $(q-1)/4$. Its normalizer in $G$ is the dihedral maximal subgroup of order $(q-1)$, so we get at least $(q-1)/2$ in $G_\alpha$.

Comment: Okay, I have the impression to understand their arguments you need to know much more then just knowing what subgroups can occur, which is the sole content of the theorem they cite (and which I have linked here). Specifically how look the normalizers, whats their order, what are the Sylow subgroups. Unluckily I looked it up in their source [15], but they just state the theorem and refer to Huppert: Endliche Gruppen, but this book I have no access to, so do you know any other sources where I can read about all of this?