# The center of the projective special linear group $PSL(2,\mathbb F)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a field $\mathbb F$ the group $SL(2, \mathbb F)$ is the group of all invertible linear maps on a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb F$-vector space with determinant $1$. If we view them as matrices, its center is $Z := \{ aI : a \in \mathbb F^{\ast} \}$. The projective special linear group is $PSL(2, \mathbb F) := SL(2, \mathbb F) / Z$.

> Is there an easy way to show that $PSL(2,\mathbb F)$ has trivial center, i.e. there is no nontrivial element commuting with every other element? I guess it to be true, but I do not see any way to proof it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g \in {\rm SL}(2,F)$ is not scalar, then there exist linearly independent vectors $v,w\in F^2$ with $gv=w$. Let $h \in {\rm SL}(2,F)$ with $hv=v$, $hw=v+w$. Then $ghv = w$, but $hgv = v+w$, so the images of $g$ and $h$ in ${\rm PSL}(2,F)$ do not commute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also posted an answer just to offer a solution I came up with recently. But yours is preferable! Maybe you want to take a look and say if my solution is okay as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

Derek's proof is great, and short. But just for completeness I want to add what I got in the last ~2h.

Let $A, B \in SL(2, \mathbb F)$, then they commute in $PSL(2, \mathbb F)$ iff $[A,B] = A^{-1} B^{-1} A B \in Z$. Let
$$
 A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}
 \quad
 B = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
As the determinants are $1$, we have
$$
 A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ -a_{21} & a_{11} \end{pmatrix} 
 \quad
 B^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} b_{22} & -b_{12} \\ -b_{21} & b_{11} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We compute
\begin{align*}
 A^{-1} B^{-1} A B & = \begin{pmatrix} a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ -a_{21} & a_{11} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} b_{22} & -b_{12} \\ -b_{21} & b_{11} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{pmatrix} \\
 & = \begin{pmatrix} a_{22} b_{22} + a_{12}b_{21} & -a_{22}b_{12} - a_{12}b_{11} \\ -a_{21}b_{22} - a_{11}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{12} + a_{11} b_{11} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21} & b_{12}a_{11} + a_{12}b_{22} \\ a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} \end{pmatrix} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix} c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22} \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
 c_{11} & = (a_{22}b_{22} + a_{12}b_{21})(a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{21}) - (a_{22}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{11})(a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21}) \\
 c_{12} & = (a_{22}b_{22} + a_{12}b_{21})(b_{12}a_{11} + a_{12}b_{22})  - (a_{22}b_{12} + a_{12}b_{11})(a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22}) \\
 c_{21} & = -(a_{21}b_{22} + a_{11}b_{21})(a_{11}b_{22} + a_{12}b_{21}) + (a_{21}b_{12} + a_{11}b_{11})(a_{21}b_{11} + a_{22}b_{21}) \\
 c_{22} & = -(a_{21}b_{22} + a_{11}b_{21})(b_{12}a_{11} + a_{12}b_{22}) + (a_{21}b_{12} + a_{11}b_{11})(a_{21}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22}).
\end{align*}
Now $AZ$ (the coset of $A$ with respect to $Z$) is in the center of $PSL(2, \mathbb F)$ iff for every $B$ we have $[A,B] \in Z = \{ \alpha I : \alpha \in \mathbb F^{\ast} \}$. So we choose the special matrices
$$
 B = \begin{pmatrix} b_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & b_{11}^{-1} \end{pmatrix}
$$
then
\begin{align*}
 c_{11} & = a_{22}b_{22} a_{11} b_{11} - a_{12} b_{11} a_{21} b_{11} \\
 c_{12} & = a_{22}b_{22} a_{12} b_{22} - a_{12} b_{11} a_{22} b_{22} \\
 c_{21} & = -a_{21}b_{22}a_{11}b_{22} + a_{11}b_{11}a_{21}b_{11} \\
 c_{22} & = -a_{21}b_{22}a_{12}b_{22} + a_{11}b_{11}a_{22} b_{22}.
\end{align*}
Now requiring
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} c_{11} & c_{12} \\ c_{21} & c_{22} \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha \end{pmatrix}
$$
this gives after simplifying
\begin{align*}
 \alpha & = a_{11} a_{22} - a_{12} a_{21} b_{11}^2 \\
     0  & = a_{22} a_{12} b_{11}^{-2} - a_{12}a_{22} = a_{22}a_{12}(b_{11}^{-2} - 1) \\
     0 & = a_{11}a_{21}b_{11}^{-2} - a_{11}a_{21} b_{11}^2 = a_{11}a_{21}(b_{11}^{-2} - b_{11}^2) \\
 \alpha & = a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12} b_{11}^{-2}.
\end{align*}
The first and last equation give $b_{11}^2 = b_{11}^{-2} \Leftrightarrow b_{11}^4 = 1$. But as the equations have to hold for every $B$, just choose some matrix $B$ with $b_{11}^4 \ne 1$ and this gives a contradiction if the field is such that we can choose such an element. Otherwise the ground field
is the finite field of order $2$, $3$ or $5$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587088/what-are-the-fields-such-that-x4-1-for-every-x-in-the-multiplicative-grou).
But $PSL(2,2) \cong S_3, PSL(2,3) \cong A_4, PSL(2,5) \cong A_5$ and all these groups have trivial center.