# Do the groups $\operatorname{SL}$, $\operatorname{PGL}$, and $\operatorname{PSL}$ over a field $K$ always have the same automorphism group?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $K$ be a field, then $\operatorname{GL}(n,K)$ consists of the $n\times n$ invertible matrices, $\operatorname{SL}(n,K)$ consists of the $n\times n-$matrices with determinant $1$, and $\operatorname{PGL}(n,K) = \operatorname{GL}(n,K)/\{rI_n: r\in K^\times\}$, $\operatorname{PSL}(n,K) = \operatorname{SL}(n,K)/\{rI_n: r^n=1\}$.

Now I'm interested in the automorphism groups $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{SL}(n,K))$, $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PGL}(n,K))$, and $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PSL}(n,K))$. I've searched for small $n$ and $|K|$ using `GAP` and found that they are the same. So are these three groups really isomorphic?

Edit 1: I realized that $\operatorname{SL}(n,K)$, $\operatorname{PGL}(n,K)$, and $\operatorname{PSL}(n,K)$ are in many cases isomorphic by themselves. For $K$ finite, this happens if and only if $\gcd(n,|K|-1)=1$ (so for $n=3$, the first nontrivial cases are $|K|=4$ and $|K|=7$).

Edit 2: I think my conjecture is very likely to fail if $K$ behaves not so well. So please assume that $K$ is finite if necessary.

Comment: If $\gcd(n,|K|-1)=1$ then $GL(n,K)\cong SL(n,K)\times K^*$ (as abstract group, not algebraic group) so $Aut(GL(n,K))$ is larger than $Aut(SL(n,K))$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is true in general that $\text{Aut}(SL_n(K)) \cong \text{Aut}(PSL_n(K)) \cong \text{Aut}(PGL_n(K))$ are naturally isomorphic for any (commutative) field $K$ and any dimension $n$. However, $GL_n(K)$ usually has additional *central automorphisms* owing to the fact that is has plenty of nontrivial maps from its abelianization to its center. The extra automorphism can be identified with a subset of $\text{End}(K^\times)$, but I don't believe it is understood well for general $K$.

A reference is Dieudonné, La géométrie des groupes classiques (see [the automorphism group of the general linear group GL(n,F)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123551/the-automorphism-group-of-the-general-linear-group-gln-f?rq=1) )

---

One way to track down outer automorphisms of a group $G$ is to study its embeddings inside a larger group $\widetilde G$, then restrict inner automorphisms from $N_{\widetilde G}(G)$ to $G$. One obtains a sequence:

$$
1 \to Z(G) \cap C_{\widetilde G}(G) \to C_{\widetilde G}(G) \to N_{\widetilde G}(G)/G \to \text{Out}(G)
$$

(Any outer automorphism arises this way because of $\widetilde G = G \rtimes \text{Aut}(G)$.)

In particular one can hope to find $\widetilde G$ such that the last map is onto, which is exactly what is done for $\text{Aut}(PSL_n(K))$ in the original work of [Schreier-van der Waerden (1928)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Die-Automorphismon-der-projektiven-Gruppen-Schreier-Waerden/86d88d630f6d66f73affca60ae76cc8f920ae160). As mentioned in Dieudonné, there is an error in logic when $n=2$ and characteristic is $\neq 2$, but later work showed the result was still correct.

S-W identify the automorphism group with the projective [correlation-collineation group](https://cage.ugent.be/fining/doc/chap5.html), which is isomorphic to an extension of the projective semilinear group, $\mathit{P\Gamma L}_n(K)\rtimes C_2$, with the transposition acting by the [transpose-inverse](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Transpose-inverse_map) map (similarly to the [outer linear group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Outer_linear_group)). However, for $n = 2$ the extra factor is not needed since transpose-inverse satisifies:

$$X^{-T} = (\text{det}\, X)^{-1}CXC^{-1}$$

for $C = e_{21} - e_{12}$, and therefore is an inner automorphism of $SL, PSL, PGL$.

> **Theorem 1 (Schreier-van der Waerden).** For a field $K$, the automorphism group of $PSL_n(K)$ is naturally isomorphic to
> $$
> \text{Aut}(PSL_n(K)) \cong
> \begin{cases}
> \mathit{P\Gamma L}_n(K) & n = 2\\
> \mathit{P\Gamma L}_n(K) \rtimes C_2 & n \geq 3
> \end{cases}
> $$
> via the map induced by  the inclusion $PSL_n(K) \to \mathit{P\Gamma L}_n(K)$.

The disappearance of the $C_2$ is actually somewhat natural from the point of view of projective geometry. This is because the transpose-inverse map represents the "standard duality" swapping points with hyperplanes (cf. [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_(projective_geometry))), but for $n=2$ this is projective line, so the duality is trivial.

The conjugate transpose can also be viewed as the *graph automorphism* coming from the root system used to construct $PSL_n$ as a Chevalley group. This is the reflective symmetry of the Dynkin Diagram for $A_n$ (which becomes trivial for $n = 2$) and inducing $g \mapsto -g^T$ in the Lie algebra.

---

In [Dieudonné (1951)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-automorphisms-of-the-classical-groups-Dieudonne-Hua/a91f3bd15e1b036bb8ac7d907546fe7c440cdd4c), the results above are generalized to $SL_nK, PGL_nK$ and $GL_nK$ (and orthogonal and symplectic groups) over a division rings, with some restrictions on the dimension and characteristic. However, he mentions in the introduction that the commutative case for all three follow easily from Schreier-van der Waerden's work. I haven't read S-W in detail (it is in German) so I can't say if the proof applies verbatim to $PGL_nK$ for example. However, I am able to deduce the results for these other groups from that of $PSL_nK$ without much effort.

Recall we have an exact square:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mu_n(K) @> >> K^\times @>{(\cdot)^n}>> (K^\times)^n\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
SL_n(K) @>>> GL_n(K) @>{\text{det}}>> K^\times\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
PSL_n(K) @>>> PGL_n(K) @>{ }>> K^\times/(K^\times)^n
\end{CD}
$$

where $\mu_n(K) := \{\xi \in K^\times: \xi^n = 1\}$. Also, the determinant map (and its projective version) are split by e.g. $\lambda \mapsto \text{diag}(\lambda, I_{n-1})$, giving semi-direct product decompositions.

This square is natural since the subgroups are centers and (almost always) derived subgroups. We have:

> **Proposition.** The natural inclusion
> $$Z(GL_n(K)) \leq C_{GL_n(K)}(SL_n(K))$$
> is  equality, equal to the group of scalar matrices.

(Note: This follows by the same proof at [groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_general_linear_group_is_group_of_scalar_matrices_over_center), except that there it neglects to notice that commuting with all elementary transvections actually implies the matrix is *scalar*, not merely diagonal.)

> **Proposition.** For the chain of natural inclusions
> $$[SL_n(K), SL_n(K)] \leq [GL_n(K), GL_n(K)] \leq SL_n(K)$$
> we have:
>
> - Equality on the right, except in the case of $SL(2,2)$
> - Equality on the left, except in the case of $SL(2,3)$
>
> In particular $SL_n(K)$ is a characteristic subgroup. (The same applies to the projective groups.)

When both equalities hold, $SL_n(K)$ is a perfect group, and when the right equality holds $SL_n(K)$ is the derived group of $GL_n(K)$. The sole exception to the latter is $SL_2(\mathbb F_2) = GL_2(\mathbb F_2) \cong S_3$, whose derived group is $A_3 \cong C_3$. On the other hand, it is the first inclusion which is not an equality for $SL_2(\mathbb F_3) \cong Q_8 \rtimes C_3$. These exceptions won't bother us again since in the first case all groups are the same, and in the latter case it so happens that $\text{Hom}(G_{ab}, ZG) \cong \text{Hom}(C_3, C_2) = 1$.

---

Now to relate the result for $PSL_nK$ to the other groups, note that because $SL_n(K)$ (and scalar matrices) are characteristic subgroups, we have natural restriction/quotient maps:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{Aut}(GL_n(K)) @> >> \text{Aut}(PGL_n(K))\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\text{Aut}(SL_n(K)) @>>> \text{Aut}(PSL_n(K)) \\
\end{CD}
$$

From Theorem 1, the maps in this diagram ending at $PSL_n$ are all surjective. For example, $GL_n$ and $SL_n$ embed similarly into the nonprojective semilinear group $\Gamma L_n(K)$, and taking inner automorphisms gives us again $P\Gamma L_n(K)$. So, we only need to see injectivity.

Recall that for a group $G$, the *central automorphism group* $\text{Aut}_c(G)$ is defined to be the kernel of the natural map $\text{Aut}(G) \to \text{Aut}(G/ZG)$ which is by definition the kernel of our horizontal maps above. It is easy to show that a central endomorphism is of the form $[g \mapsto \chi(g)g]$ for $\chi \in \text{Hom}(G_{ab}, ZG)$. When $SL_n(K)$ is perfect, this group vanishes. This also vanishes in the two exceptional cases, for example since $SL(2,3)_{ab} \cong C_3$ but $Z(SL(2,3)) \cong C_2$. So the bottom map is injective.

As for the vertical maps, we can show that in this case, the kernels happen to also be the respective central automorphism groups.

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group such that $G \cong H \rtimes T$, where $H$ is a characteristic subgroup such that $C_G(H) = Z(G)$. Then the sequence
> $$1 \to \text{Aut}_c(G) \to \text{Aut}(G) \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(H)$$
> is exact.

*Proof.* Given $\Phi \in \text{Aut}_H(G)$ extending $\text{id}_H$, we set $\chi(x) := x^{-1}\Phi(x)$ which satisfies $\chi(h.t) = \chi(t)$. Then we compute:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi(t \cdot h) &= \Phi(tht^{-1}.t)\\ &= tht^{-1}\Phi(t)\\ &= t\cdot h\cdot \chi(t)\\
\Phi(t)\cdot\Phi(h) &= \Phi(t)h\\ &= t\cdot \chi(t) \cdot h
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $[h, \chi(t)] = 1$, or $\chi(t) \in C_G(H)$. From $C_G(H) \subset Z(G)$, it then follows that this is a central homomorphism. $\square$

Since $PGL_n(K)$ is [centerless](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586813/the-center-of-the-projective-special-linear-group-psl2-mathbb-f), its central automorphisms vanish too and the right vertical map is an injection.

> **Corollary.** For any field $K$, we have natural isomorphisms
> $$\text{Aut}(PGL_nK) \cong \text{Aut}(SL_nK) \cong \text{Aut}(PSL_nK)$$
> and
> $$\text{Aut}(GL_nK) \cong \text{Aut}_c(GL_nK)\rtimes\text{Aut}(PSL_nK)$$

The inner/outer automorphism structure splits up differently depending on $GL$ vs $SL$ via:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathit{P\Gamma L}_nK &\cong PGL_nK \rtimes \text{Aut}(K)\\
&= PSL_nK \rtimes (K^\times/(K^\times)^n) \rtimes \text{Aut}(K)
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that the factor of $K^\times/(K^\times)^n$ are the *diagonal automorphisms* in the classification in Steinberg (cf. [Automorphisms of Linear Groups (1960)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/16023F257E0F21D57873B1450E9F15E4/S0008414X00010245a.pdf/automorphisms-of-finite-linear-groups.pdf))

---

We have addressed the main question, no we look at $\text{Aut}_c(GL_n(K))$ only for a finite field.

It's worth noting that although there is a correspondence (called the *Adney-Yen* mapping), $$\text{Aut}_c(G) \hookrightarrow \text{Hom}(G, ZG)$$ defined by $\phi \mapsto [g \mapsto g^{-1}\phi(g)]$, this is not in general a bijection. Instead the right hand side is in bijection with central *endomorphisms* $\text{End}_c(G)$, which is in general larger than $\text{Aut}_c(G)$. We can characterize the image:

> **Proposition.** Let $\chi \in \text{Hom}(G,ZG)$ and $\phi \in \text{End}_c(G)$ be such that $\phi(g)g^{-1} = \chi(g)$. Then
>
> 1. $\phi$ is injective if and only if $\chi(g) = g^{-1}$ implies $g = 1$
> 2. $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $\chi(g)^{-1} = \chi(z)z$ for some $z \in ZG$

Any two such $z, z'$ in (2.) satisfy $\phi(z) = \phi(z')$, so that for automorphisms this element is unique, and in this way we obtain the element $\overline{\chi} \in \text{Hom}(G, ZG)$ corresponding to $\phi^{-1}$.

Consider a finite field $|K| = q + 1$, then $K^\times \cong C_q$ and $\text{Hom}(G, ZG) \cong \text{End}(C_q) \cong C_q$, given by $m\in C_q \longleftrightarrow [A \mapsto (\text{det} A)^mA]$
with composition on the right corresponding to the operation
$m_1 \circ m_2 = m_1 + m_2 + nm_1m_2$ in $C_q$ (the $n$ comes from the determinant). It suffices to check injectivity, which can be checked on scalar matrices and is equivalent to $\lambda^{nm+1} = 1 \iff \lambda = 1$, or $\text{gcd}(nm + 1, q) = 1$.

Let $a = \text{gcd}(n, q)$ and factor $q = \hat ab$ where $\hat a$ is the maximal divisor with $\text{rad}(\hat a) = \text{rad}(a)$ (and $b$ is the maximal divisor such that $\text{gcd}(a, b) = 1$). By the remainder theorem $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z/\hat a\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$, such that $nm+1 = (n_am_a + 1, n_bm_b + 1)$. All elements of the form $n_am_a + 1$ in $\mathbb Z/{\hat a}\mathbb Z$ are units in the coset $1 + a\mathbb Z/{\hat a}\mathbb Z$, whereas all elements of $\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ (in particular the units) are of the form $n_bm_b + 1$ by invertibility of $n$ mod $b$.

Thus
$
\text{Aut}_c(GL_n(q+1))
\cong (1 + a\mathbb Z/\hat a\mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z)^\times\\
$ and the factor on the left is also the kernel of $(\mathbb Z/(\hat a/a)\mathbb Z)^\times \to (\mathbb Z/\text{rad}(\hat{a}/a)\mathbb Z)^\times$.

In other words, we get the full unit groups coming from the primes dividing $q$ but not $n$, and for the power two, but only the $p$-torsion part for odd primes $p$ diving both $q$ and $n$.

Comment: Very detailed answer indeed. I like it! Thanks a lot for your elaboration.

Comment: I have just one question: I have heard that $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PGL}(2,p)) = \operatorname{PGL}(2,p)$ for primes $p$, so is the case $n=2$ special? it seems that the extra $C_2$ factor does not exist in this case?

Comment: Also for the $\operatorname{GL}$ case, ```GAP``` gives $|\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{GL}(3,4))| / |\operatorname{PGL}(3,4)| = 12$, so could you please check the formula for $\operatorname{GL}$ :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135371/discussion-between-jianing-song-and-ben).

Comment: Apologies - the factor in GL corresponding to radial automorphisms is simply not correct, and also the transpose map is inner for dimension 2. I will edit the answer when i have a chance but it may be a couple days

Comment: Ok, take your time :)

Comment: @JianingSong Updated :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work!