# Automorphisms of $ SL(n,q) $ coming from $ GL(n,q) $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, automorphism-group, simple-groups

For which values of $ n \geq 2 $ and $ q $ a prime power are all automorphisms of $ SL(n,q) $ induced by conjugation by elements of $ GL(n,q) $?

---

Old version of the question:

$ \Sigma L(n,q) $ is an almost quasisimple group defined to be the subgroup of $ GL(n,q) $ generated by the quasisimple group $ SL(n,q) $ together with all elements $ g \in GL(n,q) $ such that conjugation by $ g $ induces an outer autmorphism of $ SL(n,q) $. For which $ n,q $ is it the case that all outer automorphisms of $ SL(n,q) $ can be realized in this way?

(warning: the next couple sentences apparently contain several incorrect claims)

In other words for which $ n,q $ does $ \Sigma L(n,q) $ have the structure of $ \Sigma L(n,q) \cong SL(n,q).Out(SL(n,q)) $?

I know for example that this is true for
$$
 \Sigma L(2,5) \cong SL(2,5).Out(SL(2,5))=2.PSL(2,5).2 
$$
an almost quasisimple group of order $ 240 $ which is index $ 2 $ in $ GL(2,5) $.

Comment: Your "In other words  ..." statement is not equivalent to the question you asked. Your example is also wrong because ${\rm GL}(2,5)$ does not have a subgroup with the structure ${\rm SL}(2,5).{\rm Out}({\rm SL}(2,5))$, although there does exist a group with that structure.

Comment: Why not just ask "For which values of $n \ge 2$ and $q$ are all automorphisms of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ induced by conjugation by elements of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$?" I can answer that!

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok that sounds way better I'll just edit my question to ask that!

Comment: Learned about this topic a while ago in a related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419869/do-the-groups-operatornamesl-operatornamepgl-and-operatornamepsl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n > 2$ then the duality (graph) automorphism $A \mapsto (A^{-1})^{\mathsf T}$ is an outer automorphism of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ that is not induced by conjugation in ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ (those are called *diagonal* automorphisms).

If $q$ is not a prime then there are field automorphisms of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$, which are not diagonal.

Conversely, for the groups ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ with $p$ prime, we claim that an automorphism $\alpha$ is induced by conjugation by an element of ${\rm GL}(2,p)$.The normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ in ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ acts transitively on its non-identity elements, so we can assume that $\alpha$ centralizes $P$. But then, since a $p$-cycle in $S_{p+1}$ is self-centralizing, by considering the natural projective action we find that $\alpha$ is induced by conjugation by an element of $P$, which proves the claim.

So all automorphisms are diagonal if and only if $n=2$ and $q$ is prime.

In fact all this can be deduced directly from the standard classification of the automorphism groups of simple groups of Lie type, which are generated by diagonal, field, and graph automorphisms.

Comment: +1 this proves the only if direction, you probably need a word on why they are all diagonal when $ n = 2$ and $q$ is prime

Comment: @hunter I added a note about this.

Comment: So is it the case that $ \Sigma L(n,q) $ is just $ SL(n,q) $ extended by its diagonal automorphisms? (in other words no graph automorphisms and no field automorphisms?) I can also ask about this in a different question if you think that would be better.

Comment: I think I already answered this question in an earlier comment. The answer is no. The extension of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ by its diagonal automorphism is not a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,5)$. But the diagonal automorphisms of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ are exactly those induced by conjugation by elements of ${\rm GL}(2,q)$.